# VPN configuration via mobileconfig is not working

Tags: macos, vpn, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator

Having some problems with the following part of an XML mobileconfig file. I'm trying to set up an IKEv2 VPN with EAP for user authentication.

```xml
<dict>
    <key>DNS</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DomainName</key>
        <string>corp.internal</string>
        <key>SearchDomains</key>
        <array>
            <string>corp.internal</string>
        </array>
        <key>ServerAddresses</key>
        <array>
            <string>192.168.246.1</string>
        </array>
        <key>SupplementalMatchDomainsNoSearch</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>IKEv2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AuthenticationMethod</key>           <!-- ====== Authentication Method ======== -->
        <string>None</string>
        <key>ChildSecurityAssociationParameters</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DiffieHellmanGroup</key>
            <integer>20</integer>
            <key>EncryptionAlgorithm</key>
            <string>AES-256-GCM</string>
            <key>IntegrityAlgorithm</key>
            <string>SHA2-384</string>
            <key>LifeTimeInMinutes</key>
            <integer>60</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>DeadPeerDetectionRate</key>
        <string>Medium</string>
        <key>DisableMOBIKE</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>DisableRedirect</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>EnableCertificateRevocationCheck</key>
        <true/>
        <key>EnableFallback</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>EnablePFS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ExtendedAuthEnabled</key>           <!-- ====== Extended Auth Enabled ======== -->
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>IKESecurityAssociationParameters</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DiffieHellmanGroup</key>
            <integer>20</integer>
            <key>EncryptionAlgorithm</key>
            <string>AES-256-GCM</string>
            <key>IntegrityAlgorithm</key>
            <string>SHA2-384</string>
            <key>LifeTimeInMinutes</key>
            <integer>480</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>LocalIdentifier</key>
        <string>vpn@corp.internal</string>
        <key>RemoteAddress</key>
        <string>vpn.example.ca</string>
        <key>RemoteIdentifier</key>
        <string>vpn.example.ca</string>
        <key>ServerCertificateCommonName</key>
        <string>vpn.example.ca</string>
        <key>ServerCertificateIssuerCommonName</key>
        <string>Corporate Root CA</string>
        <key>UseConfigurationAttributeInternalIPSubnet</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Configures VPN settings</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>VPN</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.vpn.managed.1226202F-7BB2-45EE-B456-B1D542015F95</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>com.apple.vpn.managed</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>1226202F-7BB2-45EE-B456-B1D542015F95</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>Proxies</key>
    <dict>
        <key>HTTPEnable</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>HTTPSEnable</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>UserDefinedName</key>
    <string>Corp VPN</string>
    <key>VPNType</key>
    <string>IKEv2</string>
</dict>
```

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf) <sub>(PDF)</sub>, if `AuthenticationMethod` is set to `None` and `ExtendedAuthEnabled` is set to `1`, EAP authentication should be used.

However, when the users install the profile on macOS, the authentication type is set to "certificate." Users can easily go in and change the VPN to use "username" authentication, but it's an extra unnecessary step. iOS appears to work as expected.

I also tried to use Apple's System Configurator app, selected "username" as the user authentication method, but upon saving it just sets `AuthenticationMethod` to "certificate" and `ExtendedAuthEnabled` to boolean true (documentation says it should be an integer.) Next time I open the profile in the app, it's back to "certificate" for user authentication.

Does anyone have any experience with this particular setup?